# Microsoft Webmatrix - Pool User

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, iis-express

I know that WebMatrix does not have Pool concepts, but can I put my WebSite in Webmatrix to run in context of a specified User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMatrix uses IIS Express7.5 server and by default IIS Express runs as current user. 
You have two options.

1. You can start WebMatrix as some particular user using 'runas' command. For Example: runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator "%programfiles%\Microsoft Webmatrix\webmatrix.exe"
2. check [how to run iisexpress app pool under a different identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331206/how-to-run-iisexpress-app-pool-under-a-different-identity/5333047#5333047)