# Authenticate against a domain using a specific machine?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, dns, claims-based-identity

### Background

We are transitioning to Claims-Based auth in our app (on .NET 4.5)
We currently have authentication via Asp.net membership & domain auth working correctly.

The domain portion looks like this (generalized a little):

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomainName);
return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

### Problem / Goal

Sometimes we (or some consultants we use) are on a VPN connection using machines that can see our domain servers, but that aren't members of our domain.

It would be a great help to test the app from a machine that isn't on the domain, rather than having to fire up a machine that is on the domain in order to check.

### Question

Is there a way to perform domain authentication against a domain controller from a machine that isn't on the domain?  I haven't been able to find any research on it thus far.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use LDAP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561689/using-c-sharp-to-authenticate-user-against-ldap) and specify credentials from your code:

```
using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", @"mydomain\serviceAcct", "serviceAcctPass")) 
{
    //Username and password for authentication.
    return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password); 
}
```

Or, run your authenticating server under `runas /netonly`, which lets you run with domain network credentials from a workgroup joined computer

```
rem if your server is standalone
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\consultantaccount C:\dev\sts\ipsts.exe

rem or you can have it in IIS Express:
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\consultantaccount "iisexpress /path:c:\dev\sts\ /port:9090 /clr:v2.0"
```

I will note that I have not actually checked whether `/netonly` will work in this context, so if you end up trying it, I'd be interested to hear if it worked.

Comment: I can confirm that runas /netonly worked for running IISExpress.exe in our very similar situation. This is a huge productivity gain for us!

We're developing on Azure VM's which are in the client's AD domain, a different domain from our own consulting development laptops.

We're using (free) SoftEther VPN product to connect to the Azure subnet. Azure Point-To-Site (P2S) VPN not an option because full blown Azure Site-To-Site is in play.

Anyway, our scenario hinges on WCF calls, from ASP.Net MVC controllers to MS Dynamics AX AIF, which must come from a trusted domain account.